# How to use conditional formatting to compare two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

Here is a very simple conditional formatting problem although I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

I want the cells in column `E` to be green if they have a greater value within than the cells in column `C` and red if vice versa. What am I missing

[image: Comparaison sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only looking specifically at cells C1000 and E1000, try $C2>$E2 and $E2>=$C2 to make the formula portable